# What do I follow Which function lifetime 'a or just scope lifetime?

Tags: rust

What do I follow Which function lifetime 'a or just scope lifetime?

```rust
fn hello<'a>(name: &'a String) {
  println!("hello {}", name)
}
```

In this case above, It seems that it has a lifetime **'a**
so, I thought about it then, there's an confusing point for me.

let me do code,

First, the **hello** function's lifetime is **'a** and also its argument **name**'s too.

So I could guess like:

**hello**'s lifetime is same with the program then,
Is **name**'s lifetime same with the program then?

Me & everyone will say ***'No'***

As far as I have known one thing is obvious that the **name** argument disappears when the function ends.
But the name argument's lifetime(it means disappears) is done when the **hello** function disappear !

if so, It is nonsense.

How to understand this?
I'm so confusing with this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `<T>`, `<'a>` is a generic. It means that it can take on any lifetime so long as `name`'s reference lives for that long. `'a` does **not** indicate the lifetime as the program, as you seem to believe it does. In this case, `'a` is simply the lifetime of the function.

Comment: Lifetime never be connected outside scope. I understood thank you.